# How to retrieve Django JSON variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, django

I'm using JSONField() to save my json data on my models. What I would like to do is to get these json datas onto my javascript as JSON. Here's the error I get :

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

My JSON datas are valid, there's nothing missing in it since there's no error from [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) and I checked it already. What could be the problem ?

**models :**

```
...
json = JSONField()  #('Layout' as model)
```

**views :**

```
...
layouts = Layout.objects.all()  #('layouts' as context)
```

**Javascript :**

```
<script>
  {% for layout in layouts %}
    var data = '{{ layout.json|escapejs }}';
    alert(data);
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data);
  {% endfor %}
</script>
```

Comment: JSON is valid JavaScript, so there's no need to drop the JSON as a *string* in your JavaScript source.

Comment: @Pointy That's what I thought too, unfortunately when I use `var data = {{ layout.json }}` I get another error : **SyntaxError: expected property name, got '&'**.

Comment: Well perhaps your JSON is not as correct as you expect. When that happens, what exactly does the source look like? (You should be able to use your browser's developer console to see the HTTP response.) *edit* — the problem may be with your use of `escapejs`.